# black-scholes market and european calls using drexel

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Given is a Black–Scholes market with r = 0.2, α = 0.1, σ = 0.4, S0 = 80. You today (t = 0) sold a European
call option based on the stock with an expiration date of T = 10 at a strike price of K = 90. You build a
hedging portfolio for that option. How much of its value will be invested in the stock at time t = 5 if its price
AT THIS TIME, t = 5, is 85?

since we are allowed to use the calculator to compute  [https://www.math.drexel.edu/~pg/fin/VanillaCalculator.html](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Epg/fin/VanillaCalculator.html)

would this be the right imput? (Below)

k=90

r=.2

S0=85

T=5 (T-5=5)

σ = 0.4

The European call value would be 55.23?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it presumed that the portfolio is Delta hedged today and held (i.e., not rebalanced) until 5 years from now??

Comment: @MarkViola my professor did not give us a further explanation for this question but he said this: It does not matter how the stock price became 85 at t = 5. It is as if the clock is reset to zero at t = 0

Comment: If the Delta Hedge is not rebalanced then the hedge position has a P&L = $-\Delta \times (S_t-S_0)=-\Delta \times (85-80)$.

Comment: so it would be:  (-.93337)*5??

Comment: What is the option Delta at time zero?